# User directory logged out while logged in

Tags: linux-mint, directory, login, home, access-control

I'm having this really weird issue sometimes where I be logged in to my user account, and then suddenly unexpectedly I get bunch of errors popping up because whatever application I'm using can't access my home directory, because for some unknown reason it's been logged out and I need to enter my password after opening up Access-Your-Private-Data.

`/home/user/Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop`

I need to know what causes this issue to randomly and unexpectedly to happen. This can also sometimes happen after waking the computer up from sleep, screen off or screensaver mode.

Comment: Add some logs maybe.

Comment: I think a lot more information is needed in order to help you, to be honest. With this amount of information, it's really only possible to guess out in the blue, and that will take infinite amounts of time. Can you share with us what you have already tried and if you've discovered any hints so far, at all?

Comment: If this question hadn't had a bounty on it, I would have voted to close it as "too broad".  There is a lot of information missing.  The errors themselves would be useful, as would information about possible file-shares and what applications you're running when this happens.